# How do I do create a table on SQL Developer by running a script on the SQL Worksheet?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

enter code hereI'm trying to create a table by running an Script from the **SQL Worksheet** and **ORA-00904** error appears.

I don't know maybe the script it's misspelled?

```
CREATE table IMAGEN (
[ID_ADM] [SMALLINT] NOT NULL ,
[ID_USUARIO] [varchar] (20)  NOT NULL ,
[IMAGEN] [varbinary] (max),
[MINIATURA] [varbinary] (max),
[IMAGEN_ALT1] [varbinary] (max),
[IMAGEN_ALT2] [varbinary] (max),
[IMAGEN_ALT3] [varbinary] (max),
[ESTADO_REG] [varchar] (1)  NULL ,
[FEC_ESTADO_REG] [datetime] NULL ,
[FEC_ING_REG] [datetime] NULL ,
[ID_USUARIO_ING_REG] [varchar] (20)  NULL ,
[FEC_ULT_MODIF_REG] [datetime] NULL ,
[ID_USUARIO_ULT_MODIF_REG] [varchar] (20)  NULL ,
[ID_FUNCION_ULT_MODIF_REG] [varchar] (16)  NULL 
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_00904_string_invalid_identifier.htm

Comment: show us your script, please - just update your question to show us what you're actually trying

Comment: that's SQL Server syntax/code/data types

Comment: I know but I'm new into this so I'm looking for some help because I'm fixing  some scripts but I can't proceed learning if I can't create this table :(

Comment: SQL Developer or PL/SQL Developer?

Comment: It is SQL Developer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one interpretation of this table in Oracle

```
create table IMAGEN (
       ID_ADM                    smallint not null
       , ID_USUARIO                varchar2(20) not null
       , IMAGEN                    blob
       , MINIATURA                 blob
       , IMAGEN_ALT1               blob
       , IMAGEN_ALT2               blob
       , IMAGEN_ALT3               blob
       , ESTADO_REG                varchar2(1) null
       , FEC_ESTADO_REG            date null
       , FEC_ING_REG               date null
       , ID_USUARIO_ING_REG        varchar2(20) null
       , FEC_ULT_MODIF_REG         date null
       , ID_USUARIO_ULT_MODIF_REG  varchar2(20) null
       , ID_FUNCION_ULT_MODIF_REG  varchar2(16) null
);
```

varchar2, never varchar in Oracle

date = datetime

blobs can store any amount of binary data

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot  Sir ! ♥☻ Do you know where this code come from? I mean , why was full of unusable code  that can't run in Oracle?

Comment: Because someone wrote it originally for a completely different kind of database. I translated it myself to fit into an Oracle Database.